# Randomise order of image boxes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to randomize the order of 4 images I have. I'm doing a flag guessing game for C# Windows Phone App, its working pretty good but the right answer is always Flag 4 so if anyone has any advice on how I can change the order of the images.

Comment: How is the order determined currently? I see no code.

Comment: <Image x:Name="Flag1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tap="Flag1_Tap" />
            <Image x:Name="Flag2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"Tap="Flag2_Tap" />
            <Image x:Name="Flag3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="7,1,3,0" Tap="Flag3_Tap" />
            <Image x:Name="Flag4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,1,0,0" Tap="Flag4_Tap"/>

Comment: @user3010392 - you need a different approach. Don't hard code the layout of the "Flags" into the XAML. Make a list of "flag" objects, and then "bind" is to a listview (or similar) in the XAML. Then you can use any of the techniques detailed in the answers below to order your list. Note, if you are using a list which isn't an Observable collection, you'll need to order it first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq. Say you've got a list of "Flag" objects, would something like this do what you want?

```
class Program
    {
        static Random Random = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Flag> flags = new List<Flag>()
                                   {
                                       new Flag() {Name = "A"},
                                       new Flag() {Name = "B"},
                                       new Flag() {Name = "C"},
                                       new Flag() {Name = "D"}
                                   };

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", flags.Select(f => f.Name)));

            IEnumerable<Flag> randomlyOrdered = flags.OrderBy(f => Random.Next());
            List<Flag> newListInDifferentOrder = new List<Flag>(randomlyOrdered);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", newListInDifferentOrder.Select(f=>f.Name)));
        }

        private class Flag
        {
            public String Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implemented a method like this to randomly pick any type of item from a list:

```
private System.Random random = new System.Random();
public T GetRandomItem<T>(IList<T> candidates)
{
    int index = candidates.Count;
    while (index >= candidates.Count)
        index = (int)(random.NextDouble() * (double)candidates.Count);
    return candidates[index];
}
```

Then you would use it for your flags, assuming you have a class called Flag, like this:

```
List<Flag> possibleFlags; // <-- You populated this somewhere in your app
Flag randomFlag = GetRandomItem<Flag>(possibleFlags);
```

Note that System.Random is a low quality random number generator. You can plugin better ones if you need them. Also note the while loop while choosing an index - this is to handle the very rare case of getting a value of 1.0 from the random number generator, but still keeping probability equal for all other values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle). Here's a nice and simple C# implementation from [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used in Shuffle(T).
    /// </summary>
    static Random _random = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// Shuffle the array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Array element type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="array">Array to shuffle.</param>
    public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
    var random = _random;
    for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        // Pick random element to swap.
        int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
        // Swap.
        T tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
    }
```

As this code is generic, you can definitely use it for an array of images.